# Auto scale beanstalk instance programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk, autoscaling

In aws console or eb cli its possible to change time-base scaling settings to an application.
Beanstalk auto scaling basically schedule actions to add or remove instances. I'm trying to change this settings programmatically, using aws-sdk maybe, but i couldn't find any options to achieve this. It's possible to change this setting programmatically or i really need to use aws console or eb cli to accomplish that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Beanstalk is managing an AWS AutoScaling Group for you behind the scenes. That's what is actually doing the scaling. Using the AWS SDK you would need to use the `put_scheduled_update_group_action` method to create a scheduled scaling policy.

I'm referencing the [Python version of the SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.put_scheduled_update_group_action) here because you didn't specify your programming language.

Comment: Making out of band changes in Beanstalk is a bad idea, since beanstalk is using CloudFormation underneath it, and CFN doesn't like out of band changes

Answer (score 1):

Unless beanstalk has added an option recently I don't know about, to do this programatically you'll have to modify the AutoScaling options properties within the beanstalk config, either through directly changing the options settings[1] in your environment, or by adding options files files in the .ebextensions folder at the root of your application[2]

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-after.html#configuration-options-after-awscli-commandline

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-autoscaling-scheduledactions.html#environments-cfg-autoscaling-scheduledactions-namespace

Note: There's currently an issue with this specific option setting where the shorthand version doesn't work, so you'll have to use the long form version